# c++ init char pointer as null

Tags: c++

i got a pointer to char in my class that would later be used to reference a char array 
the size in unknown to me , and for that reason i want to refere to it as char*

i can't seem to assign it the value of null.

it is only shown as Bad Ptr exception

how can i initalize it so in my ctor i could allocate space for the "char array"
this is what i am trying to accomplish, seems simple enough if it was written in c.

```
     ctor
     {
          if( m_data != NULL )
                   m_data = new char[m_size];
     }
```

Comment: You'll probably be better off using `std::vector<char>` (or possibly `std::string`). If for some reason you really need to manage the memory yourself, don't forget the destructor, copy constructor and copy-assignment operator.

Comment: thanks , 
and yes i need to manage it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't test uninitialized data for NULL, just do:

```
MyClass::MyClass(): // ctor
  m_size(/* something appropriate */), // Note: m_size must precede m_data in the
                                       //       class' definition
  m_data(new char[m_size])
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

using the initializer list:

```
ctor(const size_t n) : m_size(n), m_data(new char[n]) {}
```

also, a `std::vector` is often what you would use in c++ for a class which has this form.

Answer (score 2):

The member variables are always there, you don't have to check for `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the object, the `char*` won't be initialized to `NULL` unless you specifically say so

```
ctor
{
    m_data = NULL;
}
```

If you don't say so, the value will be garbage, and will invoke undefined behaviour if you use/dereference it.

Later when you want to create the array you can :

```
method
{
    if(!m_data)
       m_data = new[] ...
}
```

or if you know the size of the array when you create the object, then you can do as others have suggested

```
ctor : m_data(new char[size]);
```

You should double check though if you really need a char*. Maybe an `std::string` or an `std::vector` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange, you could try setting the pointer to '\0' or 0 and compare to that.  After it points to something it should have a memory address, so it won't be zero.